# Given a primitive root $r$ mod $p$, why is all $r^m, m\in GCD(\phi(p),m)=1$ incongruent primitive root to r?

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

Given a primitive root $r$ mod $p$, why is all $r^m, m\in GCD(\phi(p),m)=1$ incongruent primitive root to r?

So I don't really understand how incongruent primitive roots are found using this strategy is *Elementary Number Theory and It's Applications*.

The example I'll use is find incongruent primitive roots of 13.

So they do $\phi(\phi(13))=4$, so that means 4 incongruent primitive roots, which makes sense, then they show 2 is a primitive root, which makes sense because a primitive root can be found if $ord_{13}2=\phi(13)=12$, which it is in this case $2^{12}\equiv1(mod13)$, but then the answer skips ahead and says any $2^u$ where u is relatively prime to $\phi(13)=12$ is incongruent primitive root to 2. Why is this? Does this hold in general for all primitive roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a primitive root exists,  then this strategy will work.

The relatively prime condition ensures you have a primitive root, since $\mid g^m\mid=\mid g\mid/\operatorname {gcd}(m,\mid g\mid)$.  This is a basic fact from the theory of cyclic groups.

Secondly,  any two powers of a generator less than the order of the group are not congruent,  quite trivially.   That is, if $m,n\lt\mid G\mid$, we have $g^m\ne g^n$. For, if $g^m=g^n$, then $g^{m-n}=e$, contradicting that $g$ is primitive.